# Delete read only files with Ant on windows

Tags: ant

I have an Ant script performing some updating etc and one task is to delete a few files and folders.

In Windows and especially version 7 there seem to be some kind of Read Only Attribute mayhem and I have tried several solutions with no success.

There are several other SO issues similar to this but no solution really.

[Ant is not able to delete some files on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77436/ant-is-not-able-to-delete-some-files-on-windows)

Is there any way to make Ant ignore the Read Only Attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ant chmod task seems only to work for Linux; searching for "ant chmod windows" yielded i.a. Attr. Then you could first make all writable. Maybe with ant delete failonerror=false.

Okay, that does not work too. Maybe use PsExec, a tool to run things as Administrator. Unlikely that a solution in the form of an ant task may be found.

Comment: Changing the attribute will not work as this is the root cause of the problem in Windows 7. Removing Read Only won't remove it..